# How to catch duplicate column value exception in Spring

Tags: spring, exception

I have written my DAO layer and service layer for my database using Spring.

In some of the tables we have unique constraints for some columns. If we try to insert the duplicate values for those columns, how do we catch those exceptions specifically based on the column name? Basically I need to know which column caused the query failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAO operations which violate a unique key will throw a `DataIntegrityViolationException`. However, you won't easily be able to extract the specific column name from this, it's just not that detailed.

If you need this information, you should consider querying the database *before* you run the insert/update, checking that the constraint won't be violated. If that check fails, then you have your information.

Comment: This actually depends on the type of database behind JPA.   When using MongoDB, an nice DuplicateKeyException with all necessary information is thrown.  When using MySQL  you are up on your own...